# Need help finding a number x so that $\phi > 9x/10$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I need help finding a number $x$ so that $φ(x) > 9x/10$? ($φ$ being Euler’s phi function.)

I also need to find a number $x$ so that $φ(x) < x/3$?

Comment: Use $$\frac{\phi(x)}x=\prod \frac{p-1}p$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: if  $p$ is prime, what is $\phi(p)$?

Answer (score 2):

Use the prime decomposition:

$$x=p_1^{a_1}\cdot\ldots\cdot p_n^{a_n}\;,\;\;p_i\;\;\text{primes}\;,\;\;a_i\in\Bbb N\implies \phi(x)=x\prod_{k=1}^n\left(1-\frac1{p_k}\right)$$

So you want

$$x\prod_{k=1}^n\left(1-\frac1{p_k}\right)>\frac9{10}x\iff\prod_{k=1}^n\left(1-\frac1{p_k}\right)>\frac9{10}$$

You can even take pretty simple naturals...say, that are prime s.t.

$$1-\frac1p>\frac9{10}\iff\frac1p<\frac1{10}\iff p>10$$

So it could be $\;x=11\,,\,\,13\,,\,29$ etc.